# jQuery UI: Cannot drag a draggable element in z-axis stack

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, dom, mouseevent

I have three z-axis layers:

```
oneEigthPageLayer, z-index = 3
oneSixthPageLayer, z-index = 2
oneThirdPageLayer, z-index = 1
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="8737662768690" class="paginationPage">
    <div id="8703675164608" class="oneEighthPageLayer">
        <div id="8246010262752" style="height: 25%;">
            <div id="8397692647995" class="oneEigth insertionBlock ui-droppable" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
            <div id="8665276236134" class="oneEigth insertionBlock ui-droppable" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="8633792988490" style="height: 25%;">
            <div id="8843350805808" class="oneEigth insertionBlock ui-droppable" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
            <div id="8254286378622" class="oneEigth insertionBlock ui-droppable" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="8236161367036" style="height: 25%;">
            <div id="8451781833311" class="oneEigth insertionBlock ui-droppable" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
            <div id="8162775614997" class="oneEigth insertionBlock ui-droppable" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="8991526000202" style="height: 25%;">
            <div id="8432879005326" class="oneEigth insertionBlock ui-droppable" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
            <div id="8143874279456" class="oneEigth insertionBlock ui-droppable" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="8667690853356" class="oneSixthPageLayer">
        <div id="8523494638968" style="height: 50%;">
            <div id="8313573412830" class="oneSixth insertionBlock" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
            <div id="8168528546113" class="oneSixth insertionBlock" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
            <div id="8442180125276" class="oneSixth insertionBlock" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="8484895223984" style="height: 50%;">
            <div id="8710337291239" class="oneSixth insertionBlock" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
            <div id="8164406366646" class="oneSixth insertionBlock" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
            <div id="8200660348637" class="oneSixth insertionBlock" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="8215678654145" class="oneThirdPageLayer">
        <div id="8509814064717" style="height: 33%;">
            <div id="8712382120313" class="oneThird insertionBlock" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="8906378003769" style="height: 33%;">
            <div id="8818719014060" class="oneThird insertionBlock" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="8169201087206" style="height: 33%;">
            <div id="8130097907502" class="oneThird insertionBlock" value="&amp;nbsp;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the relevant css:

```
.oneThirdPageLayer {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
}

.oneSixthPageLayer {
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100%;
}

.oneEighthPageLayer {
    z-index: 3;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I dynamically create elements in these layers of the class "insertion".  I then bind draggable to them like this:

```
$('.insertion').draggable({
    start: handleDragStart
});

function handleDragStart( event, ui ) {
    console.log('hi');
    var $insertion = ui.helper,
        insertion = getInsertion($insertion.attr('id'));

    // This insertion is in the air now... it has no blocks
    insertion.insertionBlocks = [];
}
```

I have noticed that I can only drag elements that are in the oneSixthPageLayer.  In that case, not only does the element obviously drag but also 'hi' is written to the console log.  In the cases that the element is visible in the oneEighthPageLayer or oneThirdPageLayer, it will not drag and 'hi' is not written to the log.

This is puzzling to me because I would expect that, if this behavior were going to happen, that it would happen to oneEighthPageLayer, the top-most layer.  Or at least oneThirdPageLayer, the bottom layer.  But oneSixthPageLayer, the middle layer?

Also, I have noticed that if I right-click on the stack and go to Inspect Element, it always brings up the oneSixthPageLayer layer.

Anyway, I need to be able to drag elements from all three layers.

How can I forward the event to all layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making the drop generate the draggable with a z-index of 100.